# Problem with struct fields in C, pls help :c

Tags: c

I have a problem with the a struct´s fields.The code compile but doesn´t work as is should, This is how i define my struct.(Srry for the bad english, its my first time in stackoverflow :)

```
struct registro {     
    char Pais[3];
    char Nombre[20];     
    char Apellido[20];     
    char Clase[1];     
    char Nivel[2];     
    char Genero[1];     
    int Edad; 
};
```

i can write on struct without problem. The words in **bold** are the ones that i typed

> ```
>                 =======Agregue los datos del nuevo estudiante=======
>
>
>
>                         Ingrese Pais     : **ARG**
>
>                         Ingrese Nombre del Estudiante     : **Gonzalo**
>
>                         Ingrese Apellido     : **Suarez**
>
>                         Ingrese Clase Social : **A**
>
>                         Ingrese Nivel de Ingles       : **C1**
>
>                         Ingrese Edad    : **20**
>
>                         Ingrese Genero   : **M**
>
>                         ______________________________
>                         ALUMNO AGREGADO DE FORMA EXITOSA! :)
>                         Desea Agregar otro estudiante: S/N
> ```

The problem is when i want to se file this happen:

> ```
>                              =======Archivos de Estudiantes=======
>
>
>                                 ARCHIVO :
>                                 ___________
>
>
>                                  Pais       : ARGGonzalo
>                                  Nombre y Apellido : Gonzalo Suarez
>                                  Clase         : AC1M
>                                  edad  : 20
>                                  Nivel de ingles    : C1M
>                                  Genero    : M
>                                  ________________________________
> ```

i discovered that for some reason the code saves the field Pais,Clase and Nivel wrong, i checked and its not a problem in the printf, i dont know why or how to fix it, I think that theres some library o im using wrong the scanf
heres the code:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"conio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

void agregar();
void ver_archivo();
void buscar();
void eliminar();

  struct registro {
    char Pais[3];
    char Nombre[20];
    char Apellido[20];
    char Clase[1];
    char Nivel[2];
    char Genero[1];
    int Edad;
};


void agregar(){
   
     char respuesta2;
     FILE *fp;
     int n,i;
     struct registro reg;
   do{
       system("cls");
       printf("\t\t\t\t=======Agregue los datos del nuevo estudiante=======\n\n\n"); 
       fp=fopen("Datos.dat","w");
        
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Pais     : ");
        scanf("%s",&reg.Pais);
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Nombre del Estudiante     : ");
        scanf("%s",&reg.Nombre);
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Apellido     : ");
        scanf("%s",&reg.Apellido);
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Clase Social : ");
        scanf("%s",&reg.Clase);
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Nivel de Ingles       : ");
        scanf("%s",&reg.Nivel);
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Edad    : ");
        scanf("%d",&reg.Edad);
        printf("\n\t\t\tIngrese Genero   : ");
        scanf("%s",&reg.Genero);
        
        printf("\n\t\t\t______________________________\n");
       
      if(fp==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO");
    }else{
        printf("\t\t\tALUMNO AGREGADO DE FORMA EXITOSA! :)\n");
    }
    
    fwrite(&reg, sizeof(struct registro), 1, fp); 
    fclose(fp);
    
    printf("\t\t\tDesea Agregar otro estudiante: S/N");
    
    
    scanf("%s",&respuesta2);
    
    
   }while(respuesta2=='S');
}
```

my profesor suggest me to change

```
fp=fopen("Datos.dat","w");
```

to

```
fp=fopen("Datos.dat","wb");
```

but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

you are putting strings like ARG into a field that is char[3]. Strings in c are zero terminated so you need char[4]. 2 rules for char string in c

- always allocate one extra character
- make sure that there is a \0 character at the end of the string